# Cedar Logic Simulator is unusable with WINE

Tags: gnome, wine, theme

So, I'm trying to use the Cedar Logic Simulator on linux with WINE. (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cedarlogic/) I am on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64. However, with the standard settings of wine it looks really ugly and is impossible to use. Attaching a picture for reference.

[As you can see the toolbar on the left does not display any icons and on clicking them nothing appears in the place where we draw the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHjQ7.png)

Things I've tried :

a) Thought must be a fault with GTK theme because had a similar issue with native Code::Blocks before (which I did not bother searching and swapped IDES). Looking online I found that if I change the GTK theme it might work. So I installed gnome-tweak-tools, however there was no option to change the GTK theme there. [Look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ybk.png)

b) Thought it must be a problem with Windows Themes/Skins in Wine, so reading from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine#:%7E:text=To%20start%2Frun%20Windows%20programs%20using%20Wine,-After%20installing%20an&text=wine%2Fdrive_c.&text=drive%20created%20in%20.-,wine.,Wine%20application%20using%20that%20icon.) (Check section on Windows Themes/Skins in Wine), however, this too lead to no results.

c) Installed all fonts with

> winetricks allfonts

d) Tried winestaging option for [GTK Theming](https://askubuntu.com/a/756781/1539756)

However, none of these things seemed to work, and the application looks exactly the same as before. So I would like some suggestions as to what can be done. If you need any more info, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all windows programs will run in WINE.    Also, Cedar Logic Simulator seems to be abandonware and hasn't been updated since 2007.  For both these reasons, I recommend finding a logic simulator program that runs natively on Linux.  Here's a starting point for your search:  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+logic+simulator&ia=web

Comment: Hmmm, but any method I can at least make it a little usable?
Yeah I know there are many better more modern logic simulators which provide native support for linux, but my college specifically asks for Cedar. Not in my hand <shrug>.